# Prevent the insertion of duplicate rows using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to insert some data from one table into another but I would like to prevent the insertion of duplicate rows.  I have currently the following query:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
(
    Table1Col1,
    Table1Col2,
    Table1Col3,
    Table1Col4,
    Table1Col5
)
SELECT
    Table2Col1,
    Table2Col2 = constant1,
    Table2Col3 = constant2,
    Table2Col4 = constant3,
    Table2Col5 = constant4
FROM Table2
WHERE
    Condition1 = constant5
AND
    Condition2 = constant6
AND
    Condition3 = constant7
AND
    Condition4 LIKE '%constant8%'
```

What I do not know is that the row I am trying to insert from Table2 into Table1 might already exist and I would like to prevent this possible duplication from happening and skip the insertion and just move onto inserting the next unique row.

I have seen that I can use a WHERE NOT EXISTS clause and use of the INTERSECT keyword but I did not fully understand how to apply it to my particular query as I only want to use some of the selected data from Table2 and then some constant values to insert into Table1.

EDIT:

I should add that the columns TableCol2 through to TableCol5 don't actually exist in the result set and I am just populating these columns alongside Table2Col1 that is returned.

Comment: You could just define a `UNIQUE` constraint on your column(s) that should be unique - then no "duplicate" insert would work (would cause an error instead)

Comment: Is duplicate row the one exactly the same as a row in table1 or a subset of columns define uniqueness?

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović It is a subset of Table1Col1, Table1Col2 and TableCol3 that define uniqueness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Intersect` (minus in Sql Server's terms) is out of question because it compares whole row. Other two options are `not in/not exists/left join` and `merge`. `Not In` is for single-column prinary key only, so it is out of question in this instance. `In/Exists/Left join` should have the same performance in Sql Server, so I'll just use exists:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
(
    Table1Col1,
    Table1Col2,
    Table1Col3,
    Table1Col4,
    Table1Col5
)
SELECT
    Table2Col1,
    Table2Col2 = constant1,
    Table2Col3 = constant2,
    Table2Col4 = constant3,
    Table2Col5 = constant4
FROM Table2
WHERE
    Condition1 = constant5
AND
    Condition2 = constant6
AND
    Condition3 = constant7
AND
    Condition4 LIKE '%constant8%'
AND NOT EXISTS
    (
       SELECT *
         FROM Table1 target
        WHERE target.Table1Col1 = Table2.Table2Col1
          AND target.Table1Col2 = Table2.Table2Col2
          AND target.Table1Col3 = Table2.Table2Col3
    )
```

[Merge](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) is used to sync two tables; it has ability to insert, update and delete records from `target table`.

```
merge into table1 as target
using table2 as source
   on target.Table1Col1 = source.Table2Col1
  AND target.Table1Col2 = source.Table2Col2
  AND target.Table1Col3 = source.Table2Col3
when not matched by target then
  insert (Table1Col1,
          Table1Col2,
          Table1Col3,
          Table1Col4,
          Table1Col5)
  values (Table2Col1,
          Table2Col2,
          Table2Col3,
          Table2Col4,
          Table2Col5);
```

If columns from table2 are computed during transfer, in `not exists()` case you might use derived table in place of table2, and the same applies to `merge` example - just place your query in place of reference to table2.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are on SQL Server 2008, you can use a [merge](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb510625.aspx) statement.

You can easily check if a row exists base on a key

something like this:

```
merge TableMain  AS target
using TableA as source 
ON <join tables here>
WHEN MATCHED THEN <update>
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET <Insert>
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE <delete>
```

Comment: Thanks Diego, I am relatively new to SQL, would you be able to relate the merge sample you have provided more to my query with the WHERE clause and the insertion of the constant values?

Answer (score 1):

we have check the whether the data is already exist or not in table. For this we have to use [If condition to avoid the duplicate insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985328/prevent-the-insertion-of-duplicate-rows-using-sql-server-2008)